# Remove one layout from listview dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am working on an application  in which I am using  custom listview and for my listview I have define a row layout for customisation.

In my row layout I have two Relative layouts.

I want to dynamically remove that one Relative layout from my listview and then add it again.

Please help me how can I do that. I have added a screen shot of my layout you can see here 
Below is my Row layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/r2_imageslayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_persontext"
    android:text="Per Person"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_8"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/result2_price"
    android:text="$568"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_10"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_5"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_15"

    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_10"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_30"
    android:id="@+id/r2_departairlineimage"
    android:src="@drawable/dl"
    />
<TextView
android:layout_width="40sp"
android:layout_height="20sp"
android:id="@+id/result2_flightcode"
android:text="SG250"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
android:layout_below="@+id/r2_departairlineimage"
/>
<ImageView
android:layout_width="30sp"
android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/r2_depart_image"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_departairlineimage"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_15"
android:layout_marginTop="35sp"
android:src="@drawable/depart"
/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_departtime"
    android:text="11:30"
    android:textColor="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size_15"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_depart_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_5"
    android:layout_marginTop="36sp"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_dep_citycode"
    android:text="Bos"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_departtime"
    android:layout_marginTop="38sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_3"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_image"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/onestop_line"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_dep_citycode"
   android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/r2_dep_citycode"
   android:layout_marginTop="42sp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_10"
   />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_1stoptext"
    android:text="1 stop"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_dep_citycode"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/r2_dep_citycode"
    android:layout_marginTop="32sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_30"
    />
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="10sp "
    android:layout_height="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/r2_departclock"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_dep_citycode"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/r2_dep_citycode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/r2_1stoptext"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:src="@drawable/time_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_30"
    />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/r2_dep_flightduration"
    android:text="5h 60m"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/r2_1stoptext"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_departclock"
    />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_arrivetime"
    android:text="11:30"
    android:textColor="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size_15"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_5"
    android:layout_marginTop="36sp"
    />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_arrive_citycode"
    android:hint="Was"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_arrivetime"
    android:layout_marginTop="38sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_3"
    />
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/result2_returnlayout"  >
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_10"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_80"
    android:id="@+id/r2_return_airlineimage"
    android:src="@drawable/dl"
    />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="40sp"
    android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/result2_returnflightcode"
    android:text="SG250"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/r2_return_airlineimage" />
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/r2_return_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_return_airlineimage"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_15"
    android:layout_marginTop="80sp"
    android:src="@drawable/return_image" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_return_deptime"
    android:text="11:30"
    android:textColor="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size_15"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_return_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_5"
    android:layout_marginTop="80sp"/>
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_return_depcitycode"
    android:text="Bos"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_return_deptime"
    android:layout_marginTop="82sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_3"/>
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/r2_ret_image"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/nonstop"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_return_depcitycode"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/r2_return_depcitycode"
    android:layout_marginTop="85sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_10"/>
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_return_nonstoptext"
    android:text="Non stop"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_return_depcitycode"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/r2_return_depcitycode"
    android:layout_marginTop="75sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_25" />
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="10sp "
    android:layout_height="10sp"
    android:id="@+id/r2_ret_clock"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_return_depcitycode"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/r2_return_depcitycode"
    android:layout_below="@+id/r2_return_nonstoptext"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:src="@drawable/time_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_30"/>
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/r2_ret_flightduration"
    android:text="5h 60m"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/r2_return_nonstoptext"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_ret_clock"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_ret_arrivetime"
    android:text="11:30"
    android:textColor="@color/toolbar_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/size_15"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_ret_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_5"
    android:layout_marginTop="80sp"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/r2_ret_arrivecitycode"
    android:text="Was"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r2_ret_arrivetime"
    android:layout_marginTop="82sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That's my adapter code:
              Result2Adapter(Context context,  List list_row)
    {
        // super(context, resourceID, list_row);
        this.context=context;
        this.list_row=list_row;

```
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list_row.size();
}

@Override
public Custom_Result getItem(int position) {
    return list_row.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
private class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView DepAirline_logo, Ret_Airlinelogo;
    TextView Dep_Airline_code,dep_time,dep_arr_time,dep_stops,dep_duration,Dep_dep_citycode,Dep_arrivecitycode,Ret_dep_citycode,Ret_arrivecitycode,Ret_Airline_code,Ret_time,Ret_arr_time,
            Ret_stops,Ret_duration,price;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder=null;
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView==null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.result2_rowlayout,null);

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder. DepAirline_logo=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_departairlineimage);
        holder.Dep_Airline_code=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.result2_flightcode);
        holder.dep_time=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_departtime);
        holder.dep_arr_time=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_arrivetime);
        holder.Dep_arrivecitycode=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_arrive_citycode);
        holder.dep_stops=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_1stoptext);
        holder.dep_duration=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_dep_flightduration);
        holder.price=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.result2_price);
        holder.Dep_dep_citycode=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_dep_citycode);


            holder.Ret_Airlinelogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_return_airlineimage);
            holder.Ret_Airline_code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.result2_returnflightcode);
            holder.Ret_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_return_deptime);
            holder.Ret_arr_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_ret_arrivetime);
            holder.Ret_arrivecitycode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_ret_arrivecitycode);
            holder.Ret_dep_citycode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_return_depcitycode);
            holder.Ret_stops = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_return_nonstoptext);
            holder.Ret_duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2_ret_flightduration);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    String retimagename=list_row.get(position).getDep_Airline_code().toLowerCase();
    String retpath="drawable/"+retimagename;
    int retimageresource=context.getResources().getIdentifier(retpath, null, context.getPackageName());


    String imagename=list_row.get(position).getRet_Airline_code().toLowerCase();
    String path="drawable/"+imagename;
    int imageresource=context.getResources().getIdentifier(path, null, context.getPackageName());

    if(imageresource==0)
    {
        imageresource=R.drawable.flight_icon;
    }
    if(retimageresource==0)
    {
        imageresource=R.drawable.flight_icon;
    }
    Drawable image=context.getResources().getDrawable(imageresource);
    Drawable retimage=context.getResources().getDrawable(imageresource);

    holder.DepAirline_logo.setImageDrawable(image);
    holder.Ret_Airlinelogo.setImageDrawable(retimage);
    holder.Dep_Airline_code.setText(list_row.get(position).getDep_Airline_name());
    holder.Ret_Airline_code.setText(list_row.get(position).getRet_Airline_name());
    holder.dep_time.setText(list_row.get(position).getDepart_time());
    holder.Ret_time.setText(list_row.get(position).getRet_dep_time());
    holder.dep_arr_time.setText(list_row.get(position).getArrive_time());
    holder.Ret_arr_time.setText(list_row.get(position).getRet_arr_time());
    holder.dep_stops.setText(list_row.get(position).getDep_stops());
    holder.Ret_stops.setText(list_row.get(position).getRet_stops());
    holder.dep_duration.setText(list_row.get(position).getDep_duration());
    holder.Ret_duration.setText(list_row.get(position).getRet_duration());
    holder.Dep_arrivecitycode.setText(list_row.get(position).getDep_CityCode());
  holder.Ret_arrivecitycode.setText(list_row.get(position).getArr_citycode());
    holder.Ret_dep_citycode.setText(list_row.get(position).getRet_dep_citycode());
    holder.Ret_arrivecitycode.setText(list_row.get(position).getRet_arr_citycoode());
    holder.price.setText(list_row.get(position).getPrice());


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Could we see the code of the layout in question and of your adapter please ?

Comment: Can you post the screen shot, and what you have tried till now.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to post the screen shot but I have low reputation on SO. So its not letting me to do that

Comment: please check my edit Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that in the adapter class's getView method.
For a particular row by inflating the view and getting the relative layout by using findViewById().

e.g.,

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutId);
```

You can hide the layout by using

```
relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and unhide using

```
relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Ok like I want to hide my layout 1, if(ring==2){hide layout 1} else{unhide it}. Is it u r saying

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Thank u that helped me and save my day